# Position M-estimators are affine equivariant (proof)

Tags: inference, robust

A position M-estimator of $\mu$ is defined as the solution of the equation (it is a $\mu$ such that):

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1} \psi\left(\frac{x_i - \mu}{ \sigma_0 } \right) = 0 $$

($\psi(x)$ is even and non-decreasing  ,$\sigma_0$ is a fixed constant)

An estimator $T$ is affine equivariant if $ T_n(ax_1+ b , ... , ax_n + b) = a T_n(x_1 , ... , x_n) + b$

How would I go on to prove that the position M-estimator is affine equivariant ?

**I've tried this:**

call $\hat{\mu}$ the solution of the starting equation, we need to show that

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1} \psi\left(\frac{ax_i+b - a\hat{\mu}-b}{ \sigma_0 } \right) = 0 $$

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1} \psi\left(\frac{ax_i - a\hat{\mu}}{ \sigma_0 } \right) = 0 $$

and now I'm stuck...

Any hints ?

Comment: Are your *sure* $\sigma_0$ is fixed and is not also being estimated?

Comment: $\sigma_0$ can be fixed or estimated

Comment: That's why you're stuck!

Comment: Hint: When $\sigma_0$ is being estimated consider $\tilde \sigma_0 \mathrel{:=} \sigma_0 / a$ for $a \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ and use the evenness of $\psi$ for negative scalings.

Comment: I'm terribly confused , even if $\sigma_0$ is estimated, to prove affine equivariance we replace $ x_i \rightarrow ax_i + b$ and $ \hat{\mu} \rightarrow a \hat{\mu} +b $ and try to get zero in the first equation, no ?  I don't get why the $\tilde{\sigma}_0$... @statmerkur

Comment: If $\sigma_0$ (viewed as function of the  $x_i$s) is a location-invariant and absolutely homogeneous estimator, then replacing each $x_i$ by $ax_i + b$ with $a \in \mathbb R_{>0}, b \in \mathbb R$ results in scaling $\sigma_0$ by $a$ and hence $\tilde \sigma_0$ remains unchanged. Analogously, replacing each $x_i$ by $ax_i + b$ with $a \in \mathbb R_{<0}, b \in \mathbb R$ only changes the sign of $\tilde \sigma_0$. See [Zhanxiong answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/643520/136579) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

As whuber commented, it is hard to prove your assertion if $\sigma_0$ is a fixed constant (unless more conditions on $\psi$ are imposed).

It is possible to prove $\hat{\mu}$ is affine-equivariant if the definition of position $M$-estimator is changed to
\begin{align*}
\hat{\mu} \in \left\{\mu \in \mathbb{R}: \sum_{i = 1}^n \psi\left(\frac{x_i - \mu}{s}\right) = 0\right\}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
where $s$ is any estimator that is scale-equivariant, namely, $s(ax_1 + b, \ldots, ax_n + b) = |a|s(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ for any $a \neq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. For example, the widely used dispersion estimator $\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{(n - 1)^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$ is scale-equivariant and hence is a legit choice of $s$ in definition $\eqref{1}$.

Under definition $\eqref{1}$, if $\hat{\mu} := \hat{\mu}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is a position $M$-estimator based on the sample $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n\psi\left(\frac{x_i - \hat{\mu}}{s}\right) = 0
\end{align*}
for some statistic $s := s(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ that is scale-equivariant, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n\psi\left(\frac{ax_i + b - (a\hat{\mu} + b)}{s(ax_1 + b, \ldots, ax_n + b)}\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^n\psi\left(\frac{ax_i - a\hat{\mu}}{|a|s}\right) = 
\sum_{i = 1}^n\psi\left(\frac{x_i - \hat{\mu}}{s}\right) = 0,
\end{align*}
where the penultimate equality holds because $\psi$ is an even function. This shows that $a\hat{\mu} + b$ is a position $M$-estimator based on the sample $\{ax_1 + b, \ldots, ax_n + b\}$.

Comment: @statmerkur Good point, I shall edit the answer to match the more general dispersion estimator's property.